# ios auto layout with dynamic size

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, autolayout

I have a View inside my `UIViewController`, it has 4 constraints: Spaces from left, right and bottom are 0 and it has aspect radio. It looks like this:

```
 ______             _
|      |             \
|      |             |
|      |             |- ViewController
|      |             |
|______|             |
|______| <- View    _/
```

I want to insert in the center of the `UIView` an `ImageView` that has dynamic size, and I want it to stay in the center. I did this resizing in code but now I want to center it with Auto-Layout, but when I center horizontally and vertically it tells me I need more constraints for the size of the `ImageView`.

What should I do in order to the `ImageView` stay in center and the Auto-Layout don't complain about these missing size constraints?

Comment: after centring it vertically and horizontally, the auto-layout is probably expecting more constraints to determine the size of that image view. Try adding height and width constraints or spacing from margin and aspect ratio

Comment: but this constraints you are suggesting will conflict with the ImageView resize and but the whole thing... I already tried to add this constraints... let me try again

Comment: if you really want to resize image in code only then just add center horizontally and center vertically constraints n leave it. Let the storyboard show red marking that more constraints are needed. It won't cause any problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question, I assume that you are setting this up in Interface Builder, correct me if I'm wrong.

Your problem is that at compile time the layout is not fully specified. A `UIImageView` has an intrinsic content size which would complete the layout, but because you don't set the image for the image view at that time it isn't yet specified.

You can set a placeholder size in the size inspector of the `UIImageView`. This has no effect at runtime but tells the compiler that there will be an intrinsic content size later.

[image: Placeholder intrinsic content size in Interface Builder]

Answer (score 1):

#### A simple solution:

**Just set an image for your image view in Interface Builder.**
*(You can use any image you like as a placeholder and change it at runtime through your code.)*

---

#### Explanation:

The moment you assign a concrete image to a `UIImageView` it assumes an `intrinsicContentSize` that's equal to the image's size. This way it has a defined width and height and if you constrain its position (both x and y) then the layout is unambiguous and Interface Builder won't complain (that is if the rest of your layout is flawless).

If you don't want to use an image as a placeholder you'll have to manually set the image view's width and height for use in Interface Builder as described in [iCaramba's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41492140/2062785).